# Is it possible to have the depth camera of the Kinect using windows iot core and raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspberry-pi, kinect, raspberry-pi2, face-recognition, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to create a new application about facial recognition using the Kinect v1, the raspberry pi 2 and windows iot core, so I did some research and I did find that I can use media capture of the new update windows 10 but what I need to know is, is it possible to use the Kinect v1 with the media capture and if not is there are some other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Kinect v1 will work with Windows IoT Core. v1 also works with Raspian or other Linux images if the RPi is your main focus.
Raspian has modprobe in the kernel which allows you to access video media (color, NO depth) - access and use kinect like a webcam.

For depth check out librekinect and look at the gspca_kinect module. the depth_mode flag should give you access to depth data from the kinect